# python curses как создать меню выбора файлов и директорий?

Tags: python, curses

пытаюсь сделать простейшее меню для выбора файлов и перемещения по директориям но из-за моей неопытности прошу помощи.

1. я хочу сделать вывод папок и файлов(большие директории просто не отгружаются и curses выдает исключения)
2. нормальное открытие папок(при попытке открыть некоторые папки curses бросает исключение addstr поэтому даже непонятно изза чего ошибка)
3. скроллинг(крутит за рамки вывода)
4. корневая директория(..) может появится даже там где назад уже просто некуда переходить
5. переход по папкам мне кажется неудачным возможно можно сделать это более правильным способом
   подскажите как можно исправить эти недочёты?

```
import curses
import os


class FileExplorer:
    def __init__(self, stdscr):
        self.stdscr = stdscr
        self.current_dir = os.getcwd()
        self.menu = os.listdir(self.current_dir)
        self.menu.insert(0, "..")
        self.current_row = 0
        self.start_row = 0
        self.end_row = min(len(self.menu), curses.LINES - 1)

    def draw_menu(self):
        self.stdscr.clear()
        h, w = self.stdscr.getmaxyx()

        for idx, row in enumerate(self.menu[self.start_row:self.end_row]):
            x = w // 2 - len(row) // 2
            y = h // 2 - len(self.menu) // 2 + idx

            if idx + self.start_row == self.current_row:
                self.stdscr.attron(curses.color_pair(1))
                self.stdscr.addstr(y, x, row)
                self.stdscr.attroff(curses.color_pair(1))
            else:
                self.stdscr.addstr(y, x, row)

        self.stdscr.refresh()

    def handle_input(self):
        key = self.stdscr.getch()

        if key in [curses.KEY_UP, ord('k')]:
            self.current_row -= 1
            self.current_row %= len(self.menu)
            self.scroll_up()
        elif key in [curses.KEY_DOWN, ord('j')]:
            self.current_row += 1
            self.current_row %= len(self.menu)
            self.scroll_down()
        elif key == curses.KEY_PPAGE:  # Page Up
            self.scroll_up()
        elif key == curses.KEY_NPAGE:  # Page Down
            self.scroll_down()
        elif key in [curses.KEY_ENTER, 10, 13]:
            selected_item = self.menu[self.current_row]
            path = os.path.join(self.current_dir, selected_item)

            if selected_item == "..":
                self.current_dir = os.path.dirname(self.current_dir)
            elif os.path.isdir(path):
                self.current_dir = path

            self.menu = os.listdir(self.current_dir)
            self.menu.insert(0, "..")
            self.current_row = 0
            self.scroll_to_top()

        return True

    def scroll_up(self):
        if self.current_row < self.start_row:
            self.start_row = self.current_row
            self.end_row = self.start_row + curses.LINES - 1
        elif self.current_row == self.start_row:
            self.start_row -= 1
            self.end_row -= 1

    def scroll_down(self):
        if self.current_row > self.end_row - 1:
            self.end_row = self.current_row + 1
            self.start_row = self.end_row - curses.LINES + 1
        elif self.current_row == self.end_row - 1:
            self.start_row += 1
            self.end_row += 1

    def scroll_to_top(self):
        self.start_row = 0
        self.end_row = min(len(self.menu), curses.LINES - 1)

    def run(self):
        curses.curs_set(0)
        self.stdscr.keypad(1)

        while True:
            self.draw_menu()

            if not self.handle_input():
                break


def main(stdscr):
    curses.use_default_colors()
    curses.init_pair(1, curses.COLOR_BLACK, curses.COLOR_WHITE)
    explorer = FileExplorer(stdscr)
    explorer.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    curses.wrapper(main)
```